# Display $ sign in observable fields Knocout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, currency

On my MVC project I have a View with 3 calculators, each calculator has its own form and I have one View Model for all the 3 forms, the View Model contains multiple computed fields and the fields depends each other.

I'm looking for the way to add a $ sign to all fields, I just need it to display it to the client and then to get rid of it in the javascript/KO code (I can't do the calculations on the computed fields with a $ sign).

I wrote the following function:

```
this.formatCurrency = function (value) {
    if (value && value !== "") {
        value = value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
        return "$" + value;
    }
}
```

But then I have to call this function from every single field:

```
<span data-bind='text: formatCurrency(improvements())'>
```

And also to remove the $ sign before any calculations on the computed.

Does anyone has a better idea of how to do that? I didn't come up with anything..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @user3297291 's answer I got an idea of how to do it.

I have the following bindingHandler to handle my numeric values:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.numValue = {
init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
    function numValueHandler() {
        valueAccessor()(this.value);
    }
    $(element).on("input change", numValueHandler)
              .val(ko.unwrap(valueAccessor()));
    ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
        $(element).off("input change", numValueHandler);
    });
},
update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
    element.value =ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
}
};
```

I added this line to remove the $ sign when I get the value:

```
parseFloat(("" + this.value).replace(/[^\.\d]/g, ""))
```

And added a $ sign before sending it back to the View:

```
 element.value ='$' + ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
```

So the entire bindingHandler looks like this:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.numValue = {
init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
    function numValueHandler() {
        valueAccessor()(parseFloat(("" + this.value).replace(/[^\.\d]/g, "")));
    }
    $(element).on("input change", numValueHandler)
              .val(ko.unwrap(valueAccessor()));
    ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
        $(element).off("input change", numValueHandler);
    });
},
update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
    element.value ='$' + ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
}
};
```

And the calls are:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="numValue: improvements" />
<input type="text" data-bind="numValue: improvements2" />
//etc..
```

That's working perfectly, without having to call the `formatCurrency` function on each field and with a few lines of code.

Thank you @user3297291 for your help!

Answer (score 1):

There's an example in the documentation that uses a `ko.pureComputed` layer on top of the "real" number value:

```
this.price = ko.observable(25.99);

this.formattedPrice = ko.pureComputed({
    read: function () {
        return '$' + this.price().toFixed(2);
    },
    write: function (value) {
        // Strip out unwanted characters, parse as float, then write the 
        // raw data back to the underlying "price" observable
        value = parseFloat(value.replace(/[^\.\d]/g, ""));
        this.price(isNaN(value) ? 0 : value); // Write to underlying storage
    },
    owner: this
});
```

Source: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-writable.html

This allows you to use the `formattedPrice` in your data-bind, and you can even write to it. `price` will remain a number. You'll need an extra property in your viewmodel for each number though...

If it's only a one-way bind you're after, you could also create a `currencyFormatter` bind that extends the `text` binding:

```js
var formatCurrency = function(value) {
  value = parseFloat(("" + value).replace(/[^\.\d]/g, ""));
  return "$" + (isNaN(value) ? 0 : value);
}

ko.bindingHandlers.currencyText = {
  update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
    var originalValue = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
    var formatValue = formatCurrency.bind(null, originalValue);
    ko.bindingHandlers.text.update.call(null, element, formatValue);
  }
};


ko.applyBindings({
  source: ko.observable(1)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<input type="number" step="0.1" data-bind="value: source">
<h1 data-bind="currencyText: source"></h1>
```